# The bot does not wait sending messages even when given a condition

Tags: telepot

I am making a project on mobile-learning.
I am making a telegram bot that first sends a video to the user and if he is ready then sends the quiz.The bot does not wait for the ready condition and sends all messages at one go.I am using mysql database to fetches the video and quiz.

my code in handle(msg) that has problem is :

```
command=msg["text"].strip().lower()
bot.sendMessage(chat_id,"Say hi to see your options")
    if content_type=='text' and chat_id in list1 and command=="hi":
        video_link=get_fast_video_link(chat_id)
        bot.sendVideo(chat_id,video=open(str(video_link),'rb'));print("video sent")
        video_id=get_fast_video_id(chat_id)
        list4=start_quiz(video_id)
        id_q=list4[0]
        question=list4[1]
        answer=list4[2]
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id,"Are you ready")
        if command== "ready":
            bot.sendMessage(chat_id,"Here is your question")    
            bot.sendMessage(chat_id,str(question))
            if command==str(answer):
                bot.sendMessage(chat_id,"You Are CORRECT")
                bot.sendMessage(chat_id,"Let's move to the next video")
```

Instead of waiting for reply from user the bot sends all messages at one go.
I am new at making bots,and have basic knowledge,how can i make this project